# Preference Attributes specific to Business Units

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible to specify preference attributes for specific business units in an Enterprise 2.0 account? It seems that right now all preferences are shared between the different BU's, and so anything that is not hidden is displayed on the preference centers.

Ultimately I want each of my BU's to have a different branding and different preference options because they are all operating and marketing individually. Our BU's do not all send the same type of communications. For instance, one may have a weekly newsletter but the other's may not. I don't want "weekly newsletter" showing up on all my BU's preference centers.

Comment: Use data extensions. It's much better suited for e2.0 setups

Comment: Are there any resources you know of that outline best practices for an e2.0 setup? I've seen ET accounts setup a number of different ways, each with its own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: I'd like to see something like this, too.  No one ever talks about the drawbacks of the data extension model, but everyone's quick to jump on it for "performance" reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E2.0 accounts [share profile attributes](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/enterprise/enterprise_20_overview/subscriber_filters_in_an_enterprise_20_account/) (and All Subscribers reside at the parent level).  No way around it.  You might check with ET/SFMC support about using brand tags to hide or show elements in each of the stock preference centers. [Brand Builder](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/admin/brandbuilder/) will let you customize the logo and colors in each BU.

The alternative is to build custom preference centers, which is nice for the flexibility, but costly for recreating the base functionality.  We generally scope custom preference center projects around 30-50 hours.